# How to get status of the message(delivered or not delivered) using Twilio extension Firebase?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to get the status of the message using Send Messages with Twilio extension. As response, I always get messageStatus: accepted instead of response if message is delivered or not. I configured firebase cloud function and statusCallBack url in the Twilio console. Can someone from Twilio help? Appreciate!